# How does the Sky in Google Earth Pro work?

Tags: amateur-observing, milky-way, data-analysis

For those who don't know, Google Earth Pro has a feature where you can see what the sky should look like based on the time and geographical location.

I know Google Sky says that Google Earth uses their information, is there any way that I could access this through an API?

If that isn't possible, do y'all know of any related databases that reveal how the sky would look at night? (Emphasis on how the sky would look here, I know there are things like the Yale Bright Star Catalouge, but it doesn't tell me where the milky way would appear in the sky).

Comment: Might stellarium be what you're looking for? https://stellarium-web.org/

Comment: @usernumber Thanks for the link! Do you know if stellarium has an API or database that I could access?

Comment: More information about Stellarium scripting in [Stellarium simulation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20018/7982) and [“Real time” Stellarium Scripting?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35573/7982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stellarium](https://stellarium-web.org/) is an open-source software that has similar features. [The code is available on github](https://github.com/Stellarium/stellarium), and [the developer's documentation is here](https://stellarium.org/doc/head/).

Some information about Stellarium scripting can be found in [Stellarium simulation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20018/7982) and [“Real time” Stellarium Scripting?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35573/7982)

Comment: `+1` If it's okay to leave the edit in place I'll delete [my comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35602/how-does-the-sky-in-google-earth-pro-work#comment70297_35602) since comments should be considered temporary.